# How can div and contents be added from the user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am actually beginner in the web field. I am learner and also working on the project. I have a problem to make a self-created div which contains contents like link and some text which is user defined. Whenever user presses ADD button  the div will be created automatically and ask user to add contents like heading (which becomes link) and then some text.
Can you please tell me which functions of JavaScript or jquery should I use?
Like:

```
                                                          ---------
                                                         |   ADD   |
                        -----------  //First div          ---------
                       |  Link     |
                       |           |
                       |  Text     |
                       |description|
                       |           |
                        -----------


                        ----------- //Second div
                       |  Link     |
                       |           |
                       |  Text     |
                       |description|
                       |           |
                        -----------

                        ----------- //Third Div
                       |  Link     |
                       |           |
                       |  Text     |
                       |description|
                       |           |
                        -----------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple script that appends the link and text description using two paragraph tags this way:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#addBtn").click(function () {
    $("#target").append('<li><p><a href="#">Link Description<\/a><\/p><p>Text Description<\/p><\/li>');
  });
});
```

```css
/* Global Reset */
* {font-family: Segoe UI; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
a {text-decoration: none;}

/* Margin for Para */
p {margin: 0 0 5px;}
/* Box for the text content */
ul {display: block; margin: auto; width: 50%;}
li {border: 1px solid #999;}

/* Style for Button */
#addBtn {display: block; padding: 3px 10px; cursor: pointer; margin: auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add Button -->
<input type="button" value="Add" id="addBtn" />

<!-- We will use an unordered list for adding the contents and use an ID target -->
<ul id="target"></ul>
```

If you want, you can add `contenteditable` like below to make it editable.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#addBtn").click(function () {
    $("#target").append('<li><p contenteditable><a href="#">Link Description (Click and Edit)<\/a><\/p><p contenteditable>Text Description (Click and Edit)<\/p><\/li>');
  });
});
```

```css
/* Global Reset */
* {font-family: Segoe UI; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
a {text-decoration: none;}

/* Margin for Para */
p {margin: 0 0 5px;}
/* Box for the text content */
ul {display: block; margin: auto; width: 50%;}
li {border: 1px solid #999;}

/* Style for Button */
#addBtn {display: block; padding: 3px 10px; cursor: pointer; margin: auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add Button -->
<input type="button" value="Add" id="addBtn" />

<!-- We will use an unordered list for adding the contents and use an ID target -->
<ul id="target"></ul>
```

Comment: The contents are not user defined. Which functions can be used to get text and links from the user? html input tags can be used?

Comment: @ZainFarooq How are you planning to get the contents from the user?

Comment: Actually I am working on a project which is business site. Like OLX whenever user presses 'Post an ad' button then a div will created and ask some description about his ad. The title which he adds will be link and some text will be the description of his ad.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Jquery `after()`. From the docs:

> Using the following HTML:
>
> ```
> <div class="container">
>   <h2>Greetings</h2>
>   <div class="inner">Hello</div>
>   <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> Content can be created and then inserted after several elements at
>   once:
>
> ```
> $( ".inner" ).after( "<p>Test</p>" );
> ```

Comment: Or `before()`. Also try `prepend()` and `append()`